# How to find list of companies whose price is increasing continuously from last 3 days

Tags: sql, sql-server

my table has below data

```
name    price    date
aa        10    1/1/2013
bb        12    1/1/2013
cc        35    1/1/2013
aa        23    1/2/2013
cc        30    1/2/2013
bb        35    1/2/2013
cc        2     1/3/2013
aa        40    1/3/2013
bb        50    1/3/2013
aa        45    1/4/2013
cc        60    1/4/2013
bb        65    1/4/2013
```

so my output should be

```
name    price    date
aa        23    1/2/2013
aa        40    1/3/2013
aa        45    1/4/2013
bb        35    1/2/2013
bb        50    1/3/2013
bb        65    1/4/2013
```

"cc" should not come in out put since its price has decreased at 1/3/2/2013

---

**EDIT**

[Here is some fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4e9ef/1) to get you started.

Comment: What about aa 10 1/1/2013?

Comment: `1/3/2/2013` is a new date format I haven't previously encountered.

Comment: Why it's 1st of the 3rd february of 2013 of course.

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.

Answer (score 1):

This should work even if my result is different(perhaps because of the date confusion):

```
WITH Invalids AS(
  SELECT [name]
  FROM dbo.Table1 t1
  WHERE EXISTS(
    SELECT 1 FROM dbo.Table1 t2
    WHERE t1.name = t2.name
    AND t1.date >= t2.date
    AND DATEDIFF(dd,t2.date, t1.date) <= 3
    AND t2.price > t1.price
  )
)
SELECT * FROM dbo.Table1 t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 1 FROM Invalids i WHERE i.name=t1.name
)
ORDER BY name,price, date
```

<kbd>[**Demonstration**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4c43d/11/0)</kbd>

Comment: Works +1, but are the extra price comparisons (e.g. day 1 with day 3) more costly that a different approach?

Comment: @Jodrell: it's not optimized for performance which depends on the indexes anyway (f.e. a non_unique_index on `Name`). The `DATEDIFF` + `t1.date >= t2.date` might be redundant. I wasn't sure, so i have left it to OP.

Answer (score 0):

```
;with cte as (select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by name order by date) rn from yourtable)
select c1.*, c2.price, c2.date, c3.price, c3.date 
from cte c1
    inner join cte c2 on c1.name = c2.name 
         and c1.rn+1=c2.rn
         and c1.price<c2.price
    inner join cte c3 on c2.name = c3.name 
         and c2.rn+1=c3.rn
         and c2.price<c3.price
```

Or if you want the results as rows,

```
;with cte as (select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by name order by date) rn from yourtable),
cte2 as (select c1.*, 
    c2.price price2, c2.date date2,
    c3.price price3, c3.date date3
from cte c1
inner join cte c2 on c1.name = c2.name 
     and c1.rn+1=c2.rn
     and c1.price<c2.price
inner join cte c3 on c2.name = c3.name 
     and c2.rn+1=c3.rn
     and c2.price<c3.price
)
select name, price, date, rn from cte2
union all
select name, price2, date2, rn from cte2
union all
select name, price3, date3, rn from cte2
order by name, rn
```

In SQL 2012, you may be able to do something smarter with `LAG`

Comment: @Jodrell In what way?

Comment: The first gives one row too few, the later has some duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

```
--Date to be used as "today"
DECLARE @refDate as smalldatetime = '1-4-2013'

SELECT a.Name,
    a.[Date],
    a.Price AS 'PriceToday',
    b.Price AS 'PriceYesterday',
    c.Price AS 'Price2DaysAgo'
FROM @prices a
LEFT JOIN @prices b ON b.Name = a.Name AND b.[Date] = DATEADD(DAY, -1, a.[Date])
LEFT JOIN @prices c ON c.Name = a.Name AND c.[Date] = DATEADD(DAY, -2, a.[Date])
WHERE a.[Date] = @refDate
AND a.Price > b.Price
AND b.Price > c.Price
```

This will return the following:

```
+------+------------+------------+----------------+---------------+
| Name |    Date    | PriceToday | PriceYesterday | Price2DaysAgo |
+------+------------+------------+----------------+---------------+
| aa   | 2013-01-04 | 45.0000    | 40.0000        | 23.0000       |
| bb   | 2013-01-04 | 65.0000    | 50.0000        | 35.0000       |
+------+------------+------------+----------------+---------------+
```

If you set @refDate to '1-3-2013' it will return:

```
+------+------------+------------+----------------+---------------+
| Name |    Date    | PriceToday | PriceYesterday | Price2DaysAgo |
+------+------------+------------+----------------+---------------+
| aa   | 2013-01-03 | 40.0000    | 23.0000        | 10.0000       |
| bb   | 2013-01-03 | 50.0000    | 35.0000        | 12.0000       |
+------+------------+------------+----------------+---------------+
```

Output format not exactly what you asked for, but the premise of the SELECT should suffice as a malleable code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more efficient solution using the [`LAG`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256.aspx) function,

[Fiddle Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4e9ef/19)

```
WITH [Movements] AS (
SELECT
           [Price] - LAG([Price], 1, [Price]) OVER (
               PARTITION BY name 
               ORDER BY DATE) [Movement],
           [Name]
    FROM
           [Prices]
    WHERE
           [Date] BETWEEN '1/1/2013' AND '1/4/2013')
SELECT
            P.[Name],
            P.[Price],
            P.[Date]
    FROM
            [Prices] P
    WHERE
            NOT EXISTS
            (
               SELECT 1
                   FROM [Movements]
                   WHERE
                           [Name] = P.[Name]
                       AND
                           [Movement] < 0
            )
        AND
            [Date] BETWEEN '1/1/2013' AND '1/4/2013' 
    ORDER BY
            [Name] ASC,
            [Date] ASC;
```

---

but, since you worked out the movement, you may as well include it in the results,

[like this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4e9ef/23)

```
WITH [Movements] AS (
SELECT
           [Price] - LAG([Price], 1, [Price]) OVER (
               PARTITION BY name 
               ORDER BY DATE) [Movement],
           [Name],
           [Date]
    FROM
           [Prices]
    WHERE
           [Date] BETWEEN '1/1/2013' AND '1/4/2013')
SELECT
            P.[Name],
            P.[Price],
            P.[Date],
            M.[Movement]
    FROM
            [Prices] P
        JOIN
            [Movements] M
               ON M.[Date] = P.[Date] AND M.[Name] = P.[Name]
    WHERE
            NOT EXISTS
            (
               SELECT 1
                   FROM [Movements]
                   WHERE
                           [Name] = P.[Name]
                       AND
                           [Movement] < 0
            )
        AND
            P.[Date] BETWEEN '1/1/2013' AND '1/4/2013' 
    ORDER BY
            P.[Name] ASC,
            P.[Date] ASC;
```